# Using '.xml' file to connect Oracle 11g

Tags: configuration, oracle11g, xml

This is my codes：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<activerecord>
<config>
<add
  key="connection.driver_class"
  value="NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver" />
<add
  key="dialect"
  value="NHibernate.Dialect.OracleDialect" />
<add
  key="connection.provider"
  value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
<add 
  key="proxyfactory.factory_class" 
  value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" />
<add
  key="connection.connection_string"
  value="Data Source=localhost;User ID=yjyb;Password=yjyb;" />
</config>
</activerecord>
```

When I debug the program, an error appear.
error:Error adding information from class TestItem.Database.RTS_RTFWS_IN to NHibernate. Check the inner exception for more information.

I'm a student,and my english is very poor. =。=  Thank you for helping.